# Logarithmic Differentiantion

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This problem requires the use of logarithmic differentiation to evaluate $f'(x)$.

$$f(x)=x^2\cos x$$
Where do I start? product rule? or take the ln? This is my last hw problem, and if someone could show me the steps, that would be awesome!

Comment: Why would you use logarithmic differentiation?

Comment: That's what it said in the book...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Flowers: Logarithmic differentiation probably isn't the best way to do this. However —

$$
\begin{aligned} \
\\ y &= x^2 \cos x \
\\ \ln y &= 2 \ln x + \ln \cos x \
\\ y' / y &= 2 / x + \tan x \
\end{aligned}
$$

and on from there. Does that make sense? (Use the product rule on the original function to check/simplify your answer.)

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x) = (x^2)'\cos x + x^2(\cos x)'$$